# Prove the equation $\ \pi -x + n \cos x = 0 $ has a root

Tags: calculus

if $\ n \ge 0 $ is constant parameter . Prove that the equation $\ \pi -x + n \cdot \cos x = 0 $ has a root in $\ [ 0, \pi ] $

I think that the function is continuous for every $\ x $ and it change signs between $\ x = 0 $ and the $\ x = \pi $ and therefore there must be a real solution for $\ \sqrt{\pi - x +n \cdot \cos x} =\ 0  $ am I correct?

Comment: Yeah. That's a fine argument.

Comment: Why is there a square root there? The square root in undefined on parts of $[0,\pi].$ But the rest of the argument is correct.

Comment: Because I asked about the root of $\ \pi - x + n \cdot \cos x $ . i think I should have dropped the $\ = 0 $ part though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you take square roots at the end (and in fact, the square root of a negative number is not real), but yeah that's the idea.

You're using the intermediate value theorem by showing: the function $f(x):=\pi-x+n\cos(x)$ is continuous and has two points $a,b\in[0,\pi]$ for which $f(a)<0$ and $f(b)>0$. Then the theorem allows you to conclude there exists $c\in[0,\pi]$ such that $f(c)=0$. For a complete argument, you should explicitly find these points $a$ and $b$ (in general they are not unique, but you should show that such points exist).

Comment: Indeed, there is no $a$ when $n=0,$ but that case is easily handled.

Answer (score 1):

You have a continuous function. Also, it is also monotonically decreasing, since:

$$
f_n(x) = \pi -x +n \cos(x)
$$
Implies:
$$
f_n'(x) = -1 -n \sin(x)
$$

Since $\sin(x)\leq 0$ for $x \in [0,\pi]$, we have $f_n'(x)<0$ regardless of $n$.

Note then that:
$$
f_n(0) = \pi +n >0
$$

And:
$$
f_n(\pi) = -n<0
$$

Thus by Intermediate Value Theorem there should always exist $c^*$ such that $f_n(c^*)=0$.

Comment: $c^*$ is unique.